# Putting live score from database using AJAX and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I'm having a database which gets updated after getting score of a match.

Right Now I'm able to make ajax get request to my route for getting the latest score from database on $(document).ready(function() and change my html to show score but it is static and does not gets updated. 
So my question is how to make this ajax request in a loop. Right now a user has to refresh to make the request again and get the updated latest score.

I am using mongoose, mongodb, nodejs on express framework, and jquery for scripts.

This is my nodejs route for handling ajax request, it returns json of match data

```
router.get('/matchData',function(req,res){
    Match.getMatchData(function(err,match){
        if(err) throw err;
        res.send(match);
    });
});
```

This is my script for AJAX.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/matchData',
    dataType: 'json'
    })
        .done(function(data) {
            $('.team1').text(data.title);
            $('.team1odds').text(data.values.t1odds);
            $('.team1probability').text(data.values.t1probability);
            $('.team1score').text(data.values.t1predict);
            $('.team2').text(data.title);
            $('.team2odds').text(data.values.t2odds);
            $('.team2probability').text(data.values.t2probability);
            $('.team2score').text(data.values.t2predict);
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert("Ajax failed to fetch data")
        });
});
```

Comment: you can also do that by sending this ajax after some interval by using `setInterval` function if you don't want to use sockets

Comment: would it be efficient, i'm trying to reduce the latency as much as I can.

Comment: it won't be effecient, it is only easy to implement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this, the easiest would be to use [long polling](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2014-12-01-http-long-polling/), but it is also the most ineffective.

Very simple example:

```
var seconds = 5;
setInterval(function runner() {
    // run your ajax call here
    var result = callAjax();
}, seconds * 1000);
```

A much better way would be to use websockets, as the score gets updated server-side you push the event to the client.

Comment: can u suggest how to use websockets I have never heard of them

Comment: @VanshajBehl, there are a lot of examples around the net. I suggest you read up and try; when you have specific issues you cannot solve by any means, you can ask another question.

Comment: @VanshajBehl I have personal preference for [socket.io](https://socket.io/) for using web-sockets on a node/express server